# Split on table column into two columns in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

[Picture of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHYeO.png)

Hello I have trouble creating a view in SQL.
I need the values for SensorID = 1 in one column
the values for SensorID = 2 in the other column.

```
|Cels | Fah |
|5    | 41  |
|5    | 41  |
```

I have tried the following script but it doenst let me have two different WHERE statements.

```
CREATE VIEW myView as
Select Value as [Cels], Value as [Fah]
FROM LOG
WHERE SensorId = 1, SensorId = 2
```

How can I archeive this

Comment: Clauses in the `WHERE` aren't (comma) delimited. Jus lie many other languages, SQL users `AND` and `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple case statement with aggregation -

```
select
max(case when sensorid = 1 then value else null end) as cels,
max(case when sensorid = 2 then value else null end) as fah
from
log
where
sensorid in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select
  [timestamp],
  max(case when sensorid = 1 then value else null end) as cels,
  max(case when sensorid = 2 then value else null end) as fah
from
  log
where
  sensorid in (1,2) 
group by
  [timestamp]
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use pivot.